# Is there a Puppeteer replacement for PhantomJS onInitialized to evaluate before the page is loaded?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, puppeteer

I have a program that is using the PhantomJS [onInitialized](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html) method to set a window global variable that the page can use when it first loads. I haven't been able to find a way to do this with puppeteer yet. Calling evaluate after creating the page but before going to the page resets the variable. Doing it in the domcontentloaded seems to be too late.

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluate(pageParams => {
    window.sharedConfig = 1; // Sets it but gets reset when the page loads
  }, pageParams);

  page.on('domcontentloaded', msg => {
    page.evaluate(pageParams => {
      window.sharedConfig = 2; // Sets it but it's too late
    }, pageParams);
  });

  let pageResult = await page.goto(url);

  await page.evaluate(pageParams => {
    window.sharedConfig = 3; // Def too late
  }, pageParams);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the equivalent API for PhantomJS  `onInitialized` is actually achieved through the [`Browser :: targetcreated`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/edc510c/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated) event:

> *Emitted when a target is created, for example when a new page is opened by [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) or [`browser.newPage`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/edc510c/docs/api.md#browsernewpage).*

Example that initializes `window.sharedConfig` for all newly created pages:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  browser.on('targetcreated', async target => {
    const page = await target.page();
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      window.sharedConfig = 0;
    });
  });

  const page = browser.newPage();
  await page.evaluate(() => console.log(window.sharedConfig)); // => 0

  await browser.close();
})();
```

If you need additional page setup upon navigation, you could use [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/edc510c/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args):

> *The function is invoked after the document was created but before any of its scripts were run. This is useful to amend the JavaScript environment, e.g. to seed `Math.random`.*

Example that initializes `window.sharedConfig` and then changes that initial value on page navigation:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

  browser.on('targetcreated', async target => {
    const page = await target.page();

    // Initialize window.sharedConfig for new page
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      window.sharedConfig = 0;
    });

    // Set window.sharedConfig when the page is navigated (before page loads)
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      // window.sharedConfig === 0
      window.sharedConfig = 1;
    });
  });

  const page = browser.newPage();
  await page.evaluate(() => console.log(window.sharedConfig)); // => 0
  await page.goto('http://google.com');
  await page.evaluate(() => console.log(window.sharedConfig)); // => 1

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Nice! I couldn't get the targetcreated way to work but page.evaluateOnNewDocument does and doesn't need to be in targetcreated

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the page 'framenavigated' event is the winner here:

```
  page.on('framenavigated', msg => {
    page.evaluate(pageParams => {
      window.sharedConfig = 3;
    }, pageParams);
  });
```